# SharePoint Column Formatting using JSON

Tags: json, formatting, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to format a column from a list using JSON, I want to get rid of the "mailto:" from the field and add a little mail icon in front of the field value.

I got the JSON adding the mail icon (at the end, after the field value - not bad for a first attempt), but no luck removing the "mailto:" from the field, any suggestions?

```
{
    "debugMode": true,
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "padding-right": "8px"
            },
            "txtContent": "@currentField"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Mail",
                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                "href": "@currentField"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: are you using people/group field or normal text field?

Comment: it is a HyperLink field, it stores the link as "mailto:username@domain.com"

Comment: You are storing 'mailto' in the text and as far as I know it is not possible to replace this through json.  Can't you use people/group field?

Comment: this field is hyperlink for multiple reasons, the JSON will replace the contents when it is holds "mailto:" to show a nice little envelope, or a globe when the contents it is a "http://www", or a server when it is something like "share:\\" - I'm just getting started with the mailto: to see how far I can go on this trail, maybe not too far, but I'm still trying to learn the ins and outs of JSON

Comment: I am still not sure what are you trying to achieve.  The json provided is not valid as per the scheme.  Have a look at this also: http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/11/10/customise-sharepoint-online-columns-using-json/

Comment: thanks dude, I'm familiar with articles like the one you recommended. what I was trying to do is pretty straight-forward: evaluate the value of the string and replace by an icon, I've seen it before but got no source code. by the way, the snippet above works, but it is not complete :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard new/edit form, hyperlink fields ask for both URL and display text. If your display text is the person's name (or any string other than the href), you can simply update the txtContent as such:

```
"txtContent": "@currentField.desc"
```

If transitioning, you might want to use

```
"txtContent": "=if(@currentField.desc!='',@currentField.desc,@currentField)"
```

A full solution including your desire to place the the icon before the value might read

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Mail",
        "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
        "href": "@currentField"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(@currentField!='', 'block','none !important')",
        "padding-right": "8px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "=if(@currentField.desc!='',@currentField.desc,@currentField)"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you didn't say whether the field was mandatory, I added a display style to omit showing the icon if the field was empty